# C# - How to parse json

Tags: c#, json

I have a json string as following

```
string json = "{\"Method\":\"LOGIN\",\"Skill\":{\"1\":\"SKILL-1\",\"2\":\"SKILL-2\"}}";
```

I am using JavaScriptSerializer to parse json

```
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer oSerializer = 
                               new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
var dict = oSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string,object>>(json);
```

I am getting `Method = LOGIN` using following line

```
MessageBox.Show("Method = "+dict["Method"].ToString());
```

But how to get Skill in a loop. like

Skill

```
1 = SKILL-1
2 = SKILL-2
```

Comment: Consider deserializing the JSON to a custom type containing the `Method` as a string, and the `Skill` as a `Dictionary<int, string>`. Then iterate the dictionary.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse json in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-to-parse-json-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

You should declare your own class:

```
public class YourClassName
{
    public string Method { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int, string> Skill { get; set; }
}
```

and deserialize the Json string like this:

```
var obj = oSerializer.Deserialize<YourClassName>(json);
```

Answer (score 1):

The value mapping to your `Skill` key is actually another `Dictionary<string, object>`. You can iterate it by casting the `object`:

```
string json = "{\"Method\":\"LOGIN\",\"Skill\":{\"1\":\"SKILL-1\",\"2\":\"SKILL-2\"}}";

var oSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var dict = oSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string,object>>(json);

var innerDict = dict["Skill"] as Dictionary<string, object>;

if (innerDict != null)
{
   foreach (var kvp in innerDict)
   {
       Console.WriteLine ("{0} = {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
   }
}
```

Or, the alternative would be to map your object into a proper `class` and deserialize to it instead of a generic `Dictionary<string, object>`.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have following class

```
public class Data
{
     public string Method { get; set; }
     public Skills Skill { get; set; }
     // If you don't want to use Skills class then you can use this
     //public Dictionary<int, string> Skills { get; set; }
}
public class Skills
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Skill { get; set; }
}
```

So you can Deserialize `json` into `Data` Object like this

```
Data deserializedData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json);
```